# Move each file in folder that contains series episode number

Tags: powershell

Hello i have a lot of series in mkvin my Windows managed storage which is outside of folder belongs to.

I want to move all files into the own folder separely.

So i have:

```
<Series name><Series season >5.mkv
```

should be moved into the following directory:

```
<Some particular Series name with differ from original name of file>5
```

So:

```
Get-ChildItem -path "E:\let\feltöltés"|where{$_.Extension -eq ".mkv"}|%{...}
```

How do I loop through each file and find its directory (based on the same number contained in the file name) in the same path, and how do I move it to that directory?

Some file name looks:

```
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:22      379313300 [Erai-raws] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 171v2 [480p][Multiple
                                                  Subtitle].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:23      379881854 [Erai-raws] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 172 [480p][Multiple Su
                                                  btitle].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:24      379553820 [Erai-raws] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 173 [480p][Multiple Su
                                                  btitle].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:20      379674991 [Erai-raws] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 174 [480p][Multiple Su
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:01      155226133 [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 01 [480p].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:01      155368716 [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 02 [480p].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:01      155040937 [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 03 [480p].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:00      155173189 [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 04 [480p].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:00      155345523 [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 05 [480p].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:00      154842118 [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 06 [480p].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:01      155226133 [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 01 [480p].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:01      155368716 [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 02 [480p].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:01      155040937 [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 03 [480p].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:00      155173189 [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 04 [480p].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:00      155345523 [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 05 [480p].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:00      154842118 [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 06 [480p].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     0:58      155418140 [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 07 [480p].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     0:59      155422799 [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 08 [480p].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     0:58      155222210 [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 09 [480p].mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:30      380933081 [SubsPlease] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 169 (480p) [221382A0]
                                                  .mkv
-a---       2021. 04. 15.     1:23      380954430 [SubsPlease] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 170 (480p) [9725A7F8]
                                                  .mkv
```

And Directories:

```
d----       2021. 04. 15.    13:32                [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 01 [480p]
d----       2021. 04. 15.    13:32                [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 02 [480p]
d----       2021. 04. 15.    13:32                [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 03 [480p]
d----       2021. 04. 15.    13:32                [HorribleSubs] Boruto - Naruto Next Generations - 04 [480p]
d----       2021. 04. 15.    13:32                Boruto - Naruto Next Generations 137
d----       2021. 04. 15.    13:32                Boruto - Naruto Next Generations 138
d----       2021. 04. 15.    13:32                Boruto - Naruto Next Generations 140
d----       2021. 04. 15.    13:32                Boruto - Naruto Next Generations 142
d----       2021. 04. 15.    13:32                Boruto - Naruto Next Generations 143
```

Comment: Are all the files named like `[numbers].mkv`?

Comment: Can you show us an example of some of the file names?  There isn't enough info here to help you with anything.  Maybe run `dir | select -first 10` or something similar and edit it into the post.

Comment: It contain numbers, words, special characters.

Updated with file, directory examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item) with a [delay-bind script-block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) `-Destination` argument that determines the target directory path for each input file:

```
Get-ChildItem E:\let\feltöltés -Filter *.mkv |
  Move-Item -Destination {
    $number = $_.BaseName -replace '^.+- (\d+).*$', '$1'
    $targetDir = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Filter "*$number*" |
                   Where BaseName -match "\b$number\b"
    if ($targetDir.Count -ne 1) { throw "Cannot determine target dir." }
    $targetDir.FullName 
  } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note the **assumptions**, which fit your sample data:

- The number of interest in each input file name is preceded by `-`  and is the last such number (should there be multiple).
- There is only *one* unambiguous target directory for each input file, based on the extracted number being contained *somewhere* in the directory name, *in full* (i.e. not as part of a larger number).

Comment: Thank you, it work overall, and can you explain there is command  which able to only select the part of file BaseName which is match on the regex pattern? I found Select-String but it only find inside the file... it is not good. maybe select object?

Comment: there is an folder with name boruto_139

So How to modify the regex to match this?  It sould work but not work: '^.*?([-\s]|[_])(\d+).*$', '$2'

Comment: @NorbertPozsonyi, try `'^.+[-_] (\d+).*$'`

Comment: but ' ' is not in case of this folder it is without any whitespace so i should use [\s]? or [ ]?

So puttern '^.+[-_] (\d+).*$' will match on  'boruto_139'?

Comment: I see, @NorbertPozsonyi. Comments make it hard to troubleshoot, especially without code formatting (which can be used, but only single-line) - I missed the absence of the space. Try `'Boruto - 169 ', 'Boruto_170' -replace '^.+(?:- |_)(\d+).*$', '$1'`. If you need further help, please ask a _new_ question.

Comment: sory i missed to tell commets was placed couse separate it from my question. It is only `boruto_139` but it occurs only once in this form

Comment: So maybe the missed part in this code in the following: 
`$targetDir = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Filter "*$number*" |Where BaseName -match "\b$number\b"`

So the \b mean word boundary. So in case of `boruto_139` the `139` number no starting point which separated with whitespace so it does not match. 

Trying to change it to alternatives pattern match:  `$targetDir = Get-ChildItem -Directory  | Where BaseName -match "(?:\b|.)$number(?:\b|.)"` , unfortunately it match the number inside number so it find 91 in 191.

Comment: Yes - sorry; I didn't realize that the `_` is in the _directory_ name: What you have will work, except if the number is at the very start or end of the name; to account for that too, use `Where BaseName -match "(?:^|\D)$number(?:\D|$)"`